# will not excute mysql statement from view in php

Tags: php, mysql, view

well i been trying to query a view in mysql table but it seems no matter what i do it wont excute, if i put exact query on mysql direct it fires, i dont know what am doing wrong and for further troubleshooting i changed the query to another one from another table and not view it excuted please find below the code :

```
$query4 = "select PageName FROM testpermission WHERE UserID='".$_SESSION['id']."' and PageName NOT LIKE '/%'";
$stmt2 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt2,$query4);
if( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2)){
die("i did it");
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2,$PageNAme);
 die("no i didnt");
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put user data directly into a query, even from `$_SESSION`, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: This is some very unusual looking `mysqli` code and I'm not sure where you learned to do it this way. The [official documentation on prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) outlines a number of best practices which would make your code a lot easier to follow. As a note you'll find the object-oriented interface is far, far less verbose and avoids a lot of common mistakes with calling the wrong method on the wrong variable.

Comment: Thank you, this is Procedural code and not object oriented

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm saying that the object-oriented method of using `mysqli` is a lot less verbose and I'd strongly recommend to try it. The only reason there's a proceural mode at all is PHP 4, a version that's long dead.

Comment: yes i wanna do the change but atm i am very concerned about this query where it works on local host and on web doesnt work

Comment: Maybe your `$_SESSION['id']` value isn't what you expect on your server, or the records you think are there aren't present. You're going to have to do some debugging here.

Comment: no i troubleshooted and put die($query4) and it gave me all correct results and i tried them directly on mysql and it worked just fine

Comment: Gotta keep digging. I can't see anything wrong here apart from what I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to trim your UserID field, try this :

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "select PageName FROM testpermission WHERE TRIM(UserID)= ? and PageName NOT LIKE '/%'");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['id']);
if( mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    die("i did it");
} else {
    printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}
```

Comment: Thank you it gave me this error Error: Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared.

Comment: [https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=42041)   change your db settings.
exemple in the com :
table_open_cache 128=>16384
table_definition_cache 1024=>16384
tmp_table_size 32M=>64M
join_buffer_size 256k=>512k

Comment: i dont have any load on the db its offline i am only testing with lil data, but thank you so much you showed me where the error is , i think i will create a query to get that instead of table view.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all,

well there seems to be a bug with views in mysql so i changed it to a query directly

[code] select `tblpermissions`.`PageName` AS `Pagename` from (`tblpermissions` join `tbluserpermissions` on((`tblpermissions`.`PermissionID` = `tbluserpermissions`.`PermID`))) where userid='".$_SESSION['id']."' and PageName NOT LIKE '/%'[code]